# Which files should exist in Kendo Ui Core for a mobile application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-mobile

I made a trial Kendo mobile application a year ago. Now I want to check it with the up-to-date Kendo UI Core version.

My previous references were

```
<link href="../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

I couldn't see the kendo.all.min.js file and kendo.mobile.min.js in the core-ui. I also couldn't see the kendo.mobile.all.min.css file.

Which files should exist in my HTML to run my mobile application on kendu-ui-core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this part of the Kendo UI Core Readme:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core#source-code-and-downloads

You can also build it yourself:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core#building-kendo-ui-core

or use separate files and their dependencies:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom